# frame on ready/load does not fire on new frame url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website with frames, now you can simply change the content of a frame with a link and it loads the page in that frame.

I want to know when this loading is ready.

```
 $(top.frames['mainFrame']['csubtextframe']).load(function()
 {
  ......actions
```

This code works, but not in Internet Explorer. 
It does work for the first load, but after changing the URL of the frame it does not see the "new"  load event.

If I add an "onLoad" directly on my frame, it actually gets fired everytime. The only thing is that I do not want the onLoad function inline, but in my script in an other frame.

What is the reason the load event only fires once? And why is this only in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

try 'on' which will work for future elements too -

```
$(top.frames['mainFrame']['csubtextframe']).on('load',function()
 {
--
```

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'on' - EDIT nvm updated jquery but it still does not work.

Comment: explain more , why ?? 'on' must be available to bind events on all type of elements